# Bind Json in Knockout

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I have to bind the fields "city" of a json type:

```
{
"italia": [
    {
        "regione": "Abruzzo",
        "capoluoghi": [
            {
                "citta": "Chieti",
                "sigla": "CH"
            },
            {
                "citta": "L'Aquila",
                "sigla": "AQ"
            },
            {
                "citta": "Pescara",
                "sigla": "PE"
            },
            {
                "citta": "Teramo",
                "sigla": "TE"
            }
        ]
    },{
        "regione": "Basilicata",
        "capoluoghi": [
            {
                "citta": "Matera",
                "sigla": "MT"
            },
            {
                "citta": "Potenza",
                "sigla": "PZ"
            }
        ]
    }, ...
```

in a 'select' html, via knockout.
I entered the code:

```
self.provincia = ko.mapping.fromJS([]);
$.getJSON("italia.json", function (data) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data.italia, {}, self.provincia)
    })
```

and in html:

```
    <div  data-bind="with: provincia">
<select class="mm-menu__link" id="Provincia" data-bind:"foreach: capoluoghi">
                    <option data-bind="text:citta"></option>
                </select>
                    </div>
```

so as to show all cities, but unfortunately I get nothing!

What did I do wrong?

dave

Comment: Can you recreate your entire code in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as (for instance) it's not clear whether you're even calling `ko.applyBindings` etc.

Comment: something like this dave http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27300/ . cheers

Comment: Suggestion: translate the variables in your code in English. It looks more consistent with languages keywords, and makes it easier to ask for help on the web.

Answer (score 3):

Tough your question is bit unclear i hope this is what you looking at finally .

**view:**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: provincia">
    <select class="mm-menu__link" id="Provincia" data-bind="foreach: capoluoghi">
        <option data-bind="text:citta"></option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**viewModel:**

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.provincia = ko.observable();
    ko.mapping.fromJS(json.italia, {}, self.provincia)
};
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

working sample **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27302/)**

If you want to show all cities in one dropdown check **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/27303/)**

Comment: ok, but I do not want so many select for each "region", but I want to select one with all inserts values in the "citta" ....

Comment: @Dave are you looking at cascading functionality ?like show city based on region selection or show all citta in one dropdown?